# jQuery autocomplete with Codeigniter, not working outside of index function

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

Tearing my hair out with Codeigniter and jquery.

I have a very basic code set currently to troubleshoot this.

Currently my index function calls my view. the view processes the jquery autocomplete perfectly with this scenario.

if I change index to indextest or any other name the autocomplete stops working. almost like the jquery output is being passed specifically to the default method of the page, being index.php.

is there a way to specify the method is must be returned to or displayed on?

**my controller is:**

```
<?Php

class Sales extends MY_Controller{

  function __construct() {
    //call parent constructor
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('sales_model');
  }

  function index(){
    $this->load->view('sales/new_order_details');
  }

  function get_customers(){
    $this->load->model('Sales_model');
    if (isset($_GET['term'])){
      $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
      $this->Sales_model->get_customer($q);
    }
  }

  function login() {
    redirect('/pointer/login');
  }

  function logout() {
    redirect('/pointer/logout');
  }
}
```

**My Model**

```
<?php
// (Array of Strings)
class Sales_model extends MY_Model{

  function get_customer($q){
    $this->db->select('CustomerName');
    $this->db->like('CustomerName', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('Customers');
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
        $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['CustomerName'])); //build an array
      }
      echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
    }
  }
}
```

**My View**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
         Capture New Order
      </title>

      <link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css" media="screen" type="text/stylesheet" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/scripts/autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
   </head>
<body>
   <div  data-role="page"  data-theme="a">
      <div class="wrap-header">
         <div data-role="header" data-mini="true"  data-ajax="false">
            <a data-icon="grid" data-mini="true"  data-theme="a" onclick="window.location.href='/pointer'">Menu</a>
            <h3>New Order Details</h3>
         </div>
      </div>   
   <div data-role="content">
   <form>
      <label for="customer">Customer</label>
      <input type="text" id="customer" />
   </form>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**autocomplete.js**

```
$(function(){
  $("#customer").autocomplete({
    source: "sales/get_customers"
  });
});
```

So as mentioned, if I change my index() method of the controller to indextest() and browse directly to that method the autocomplete stops working.

Am I missing something simple or is there a greater reason I cant work out?

Thanks as always for the help,

**UPDATE AS PER FABIO**
the output from google chrome developer on calling the autocomplete script

normal index()working)
[image]

indextext()
[image]

Comment: my first shoot is that request for "sales/get_customers" misses. Check if browser sends request and gets response from server.

Comment: Thanks Saram, can I ask you to guide me round checking the browser send and response piece. I do have firefox with firebug and chrome. Thanks again.

Comment: i can see you got answer, you screen shows exactly what i mean - lookup source misses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this

```
    $(function(){
  $("#customer").autocomplete({
    source: "sales/get_customers"
  });
});
```

Do this

```
$(function(){
  $("#customer").autocomplete({
    source: "<?=site_url('sales/get_customers')?>"
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes you can try it, if you haven't changed anything base_url will wcho the same but without the index.php on the url

Comment: Another thing to helps us out, are you using google chrome? if yes open the developers tools, (just right click inside your page and choose the inspect element option) then go to the tab network and on the bottom you have a label that says XHR, press it. Now try calling the autocomplete, and see if any requests appears on the console

Comment: So with your help, it cant find path `indextest?term=a
/sales/sales/get_customers`? I am not sure on why the sales/sales is repeated. ideas?

Comment: what's this indextext()? you said that index() works fine, but indextext() doesn't. I can't find any indextext() one the code you posted

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26093/discussion-between-smudger-and-fabio-antunes)

Comment: So reason for failing was in the autocomplete.js, removed the controller name and just left the method. workign 100% now.

`$(function(){
  $("#customer").autocomplete({
    source: "get_customers"
  });
});`

Answer (score 1):

The `index` method within controller `Sales` gets called by default if a second uri parameter is not present, you have actually answered you self.

Because you now load the view using the url `sales/indextest` you need to adjust your `source` url, `sales/get_customers` is a relative url which works when you load the auto complete without specifying a second parameter `indextest`, as for the solution you might want to add a full url to the source for example `soruce:"<?=base_url();?>sales/indextest"`

You also might want to output json as following:

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data));
```

insted of:

```
json_encode($row_set);
```

Comment: Thanks Eldar, tried both these solutions with no luck. any other ideas? Thanks,